# get individual frames from gif image in matlab

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, frame, matlab

I want to find all frame individual this gif image.I means i want to convert gif image into seperate jpeg images but in matlab.
Please suggest me how can i do this?
I attached the link my project gif image.

http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=gif+images+cartoons&hl=en&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&tbnid=e0VLnXandtYxqM:&imgrefurl=http://en.loadtr.com/Animated_Bear_Gif_Cartoons-410732.htm&docid=idgHmoJKk_ue8M&imgurl=http://img1.loadtr.com/b-410732-Animated_Bear_Gif_Cartoons.gif&w=338&h=290&ei=_KvnUf6WLMa9kAXwjYHoAg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:0,s:0,i:85&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=177&tbnw=206&start=0&ndsp=14&tx=114&ty=101

Comment: I once ate mashed potatoes with a Phillips screwdriver. I think, you will have similar experience. Why use `matlab` for that, when there are millions of more suitable tools?

Comment: ya sir you are right but i have a project which i have to complete by using matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `imread` to read all frames at once, or read them one by one, as explained [here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/imread.html#f25-722074).

Example from [this post](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/26148) on MATLAB Central:

```
allframedata = imread('YourFile.GIF', 'frames', 'all');
```

OR

```
for i = 1:N      % N is the number of frames
    image = imread('YourFile.GIF', i);
    filename = ['PathToFolder' '\\' int2str(i) '.png'];
    imwrite(image, filename);
end
```

Comment: sorry sir i think that i didn't explain my problem actually i already use this command it's only read frames but i want to display all the frame in a folder like suppose i have a 23 frame it will show all 23 frame separately as a image.

Comment: In the above answer, the variable `allframedata` will contain all the frames as an array. I've edited the answer to also include an example to read the frames iteratively and save them into files.

Comment: Thank you so much sir it's work but i have a another problem it provided black & white image i wanna color image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imread()`. That will get you a Matrix (or was it a cell) with all the frames.